# Inconsistent behavior of enum as constrained parameter in generic

Tags: enums, typescript

Why it is not possible to cast something that extends `number` to `number`?

Here is simple example in which I'm trying to pass enum as a generic argument to function.

```
enum Ev {A, B}

function fun<E extends number>(x: {[ix: number]: any}, e: E)
{
    return x[<number>e]
}

// no error here, so I assume is true that `Ev extends number`
fun({0:0}, Ev.A)
```

It seems a bit inconsistent that some type `extends number` but I get this error when trying to cast it to `number`:

> Neither type 'E' nor type 'number' is assignable to the other.

**Edit**: Here is almost the same example but with class instead of `number` (this compiles without error):

```
class A {}

function fun<E extends A>(x: {[ix: number]: any}, e: E)
{
    return x[<A>e]
}
```

Comment: FYI: For others who may find this in the future, you can upcase to object type '{}', and downcast to number: `<number><{}>e`, or use the 'any' type `<number><any>e`.

Comment: FWIW I think this is a deficit in the language spec. Logged a bug at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2694

Answer (score 2):

Primitive types cannot be inherited from, as some have special "abilities" that require a special instance, and creating a new derived object would prevent that ability.  For instance, there is no way to call the string constructor for a new custom derived object, so no way to apply it to a user instance.  This is why nothing inherits from number, or anything else.

Comment: It answers your original title (see again), and I updated it for the number.  If "enum as constrained parameter" is wrong, you should change it.

Comment: Downvoted because the answer conflates the type of an enum object with the type of its members. The type of `Test` is an object type, but the type of `Test.A` is a number-like type.

Comment: I don't think I got across what I wanted too, but in after thought, I don't think I understood his question until I took another look.  I removed that part, thanks.

Comment: I'm not trying to inherit from `number` in my code. I'm relying on the fact that enum is treated as a subtype of `number` (`fun<Ev>(..)` typechecks). The problem is that something that is a subtype of `number` can not be upcasted to `number` (`<number>e` fails).

Comment: I agree it seems very inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

> Why it is not possible to cast something that extends number to number?

As Ryan has pointed out in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2694#issue-67462206), it seems like a bug in the language; however, take note that this form of constraint is only useful when the return type of the function is the constraint on the type parameter. For example:

```
function f<T extends number>(input: T) : T { return input; }
var t = f(Ev.A); // t : Ev
```

An issue with the constraint in the function you provided, is that it doesn't prevent passing in a number value. Since it's not possible to constrain to an enum member, you might as well just define your function with the constraint on the parameter instead:

```
function fun(x: {[ix: number]: any}, e: number)
{
    return x[e];
}
```

A complaint you had with doing this was that it wasn't self documenting code. I would say it's better to give your function a *descriptive name* that says its intent rather than relying on generics that offer no constraint benefit beyond a `number` constraint. Also remember that there's no way to force a developer to write the generic part when calling the function. They can easily write `fun({0:0}, Ev.A)` instead of `fun<Ev>({0:0}, Ev.A)`.

Comment: It works also if you cast it to `any` but it should be casted to `number` without any explicit casts.

Comment: @maxtaldykin a `Number` isn't necessarily a `number` so a cast is necessary. But why not just use `e: number`?

Comment: @maxtaldykin ok, but I think your assumption that an enum member `extends number` is incorrect

Comment: then why `fun<Ev>({0:0}, Ev.A)` typechecks without any warning?

Comment: @maxtaldykin i think for the same reason that `fun({0:0}, 1);` compiles.

Comment: `fun({0:0}, 1)` compiles because `1` is `number` and it is really `fun<number>(...)`

Comment: @maxtaldykin yes that's true. What I meant by saying that though was that the reason it might compile with `extends number` is that an enum member might just be a special way of using `number` and not a type that extends from `number`. I think it doesn't extend from `number` and that it's just a special language construct.